# Creating custom permalink tags in the database

Tags: permalinks, database

Is there a way to create custom permalink tags (%customtag%) in the WordPress database and/or programatically?

I am having a hard time looking through the database structure finding where in the database the custom tag information is stored as well.

Note: I found articles online pointing that permalink settings is stored in the wp_options table, however it is not there.

Comment: They're not stored in the database. They're registered with [`add_rewrite_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/).

Comment: Could you please explain further, and if you have any suggestions on how to integrate it into a database?